# How to limit dropdown list to options based on 'active' rows from lookup table, for webpage using php and postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table country with a lookup table country_type. My lookup table has 50 country types (varchar), but only 20 are 'active' in the current db (with the rest possibly used later). On the webpage I am creating I can set it up to add a filter by country type based on the country_type varchar, but all 50 types are listed, but I only want the 20 that currently used and therefore relevant to searches (I don't want to see a "There are no records to display" message). What WHERE condition can I use to achieve this?

Main table country country_id pk, col2, col3, country_type_id (fk) integer

lookup table country_type country_type_id pk, type_name varchar

Answer (score 0):

What is your "active" column? is it boolean, varchar, or what?

if it is boolean and 1 means active do this:

```
WHERE active=1
```

Comment: What is your "active" column? - As mentioned, the lookup table has 50 country types, which are varchar; the column in the table country is the fk to the table country_type and set up to be filtered by the country type varchar

Comment: Can you post the table structure?